# 404 redirects and google analytics question

Tags: redirects, 404, analytics

I read this article and setup my single entry pages with the 404 redirect conditional. I also setup the 404 page in the CP and set Strict URL's to YES. When I try and go to a broken link I do get redirected to the 404 page, but it still has the broken URL in the browser. I have analytics installed on the 404 template but I'm wondering how this will show up in Google Analytics. I want to be able to see what URL people are visiting and getting the 404. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Please, add a sample of your code and the name and directory of the 404 template. Looks like the redirect isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SEO purposes, I don't think it's a good idea to return a 301 redirect when you want to return a 404 error.

When you do {redirect="404"} then EE serves the 404 template with a proper [HTTP 404 status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) response.

When you do {redirect="404/index"} then EE responds with a [HTTP 301 status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirect header.

Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools track when a URL responds with a 404 error, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

On our EE site, we are doing any forced redirects with this code:

```
{redirect="sorry/index"}
```

The URL changes accordingling to the 404 Error Page.

Comment: I had {redirect="404"} instead of {redirect="404/index"}, it's redirecting to the 404 page with the 404 url now. Thanks for pointing out my oversight!